# How to get the index of $Matches index that satisfy certain criteria?

Tags: regex, powershell

I will be reading a text files and filtered it to the lines that I only need, then using regex to extract the content. After that, I would be finding the value that is smaller than certain value and get its index. With that index I'll be repeat be repeating the steps mentioned and extract another matches. I stuck at after getting the group of the matches. How do I proceed? Example below is only a line of the text file for easy of explanation.

```
$content=Get-Content -Path "C:\log.txt"
$content | Select-String -Pattern 'encoded' | ForEach-Object {
     if($_ -match "(.*) ([0-9]*) (.*),(.*)"){
         $Matches[2]         
     }
}
```

`$Matches[2]` would be something like:

```
0
66785
3434
125
0
24324
0
55
```

I'm trying to get the index of the value that's smaller than `30`, so that I could extract the next information I want from another regex matching of the same file.

```
$content=Get-Content -Path "C:\log.txt"
$content | Select-String -Pattern 'Input' | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "(.*) '(.*)':"){
        $Matches[2]
        # How do I extract the content of the $Matches[2] here from the previously obtained indexes?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! Appreciate any help!

*Some* of the input file content. The real file would have repeated blocks of this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\myvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\output\myvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.15.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(progressive), 864x480, q=2-31, 12800 tbn (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:

encoded 2058 frames, 1376.59 fps, 373.36 kbps, 3.66 MB
```

Comment: I think it would help a great deal if you add (a portion) of the file in the question.

Comment: The `-Pattern 'LineWiththeStringIWant'` could/should also contain the RegEx from the -match - this way you can access the $_.Line/$_.LineNumber/$_.Matches.Groups.Value properties and investigate further. sls also has the -context parameter if you are interested in pre/post context.

Comment: The "index of the value"? You mean the line number in the file? Or the index of the group in `$Matches`? Or the position of the match inside the string? or...?

Comment: What are you attempting to find/return exactly? Just that last line? What specific value? Or are you trying to get context from each value. Is there only one line that starts with "encoded"?

Comment: @marsze sorry I should be clearer. It's the index of the value in $Matches. For  example in the $Matches list above, I would get 1, 5 and 7 (zero value) as the index.

Comment: `for($index=0;$index -lt $matches[2].count;$index+=1){if([int]$matches[2][$index] -lt 30){$index}}`? Cycle each value of `$matches[2]` and return the index if the value is less that 30? However I think there might be a way to better target your searching in this.

Comment: @Matt the file will be a lot messier than the one I put up, and there will be a lots of lines that starts will 'encoded', so does 'Input'. However all extracted will have the same index, and each value at specific index is corresponding to each other. For example in the file content above, `0` is equivalent to `C:\myvideo.mp4`. In simple words, I'm trying to get the filename that has encoded frames less than 30.

Comment: That is what I wanted to here. So each file with have multiple blocks like you show above that will correspond to multiple files you are processing yes? You would skip that entry since it has > 30 encoded frames? Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes exactly what I meant! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misconception in the question. `$matches[2]` would not be an array of values you need to index. It would represent a scalar value for each interation of the `foreach-object` block. Those results are all sent down the pipeline *individually*.

I would still like to answer the question as stated though. Given an array of values, determine which of those is below a threshold and return the index of its position in the array.

```
$results = $content | Select-String -Pattern 'encoded' | 
    Where-object{$_ -match "(.*) ([0-9]*) (.*),(.*)"} | 
    ForEach-Object{$Matches[2]}
```

This is similar to the code you show above. It saves the values into an array called `$results`.

```
$threshold = 30
for($index=0; $index -lt $results.count; $index++){
    if([int]$results[$index] -lt $threshold){
        Write-Host "The value at index $index is $($results[$index]) which is below $threshold"
    }
}
```

Then we cycle the array elements, one by one, using a counter. Check every value and report the index we were currently at.

Given the scenario, I would go a different route altogether

---

I would like to take this in a *slightly* different direction. Understanding that each file with have multiple blocks like you show in the question that will correspond to multiple files you are processing and you are only interested in files where there are less than 30 encoded frames.

**Note**: This solution is heavily dependent on how the real data looks. I can only go on based what is in the question. If the real data deviates too much from that the solution is not guaranteed to work or give expected results.

Using `[regex]` lets split the file into its chunks. [Using names capture groups](https://www.petri.com/powershell-string-parsing-with-named-captures-and-regex) we can pull just the values from each "block" that you want. Non-greedy captures will ensure we don't match outside of any given block. Then we make custom objects that we can filter just like you would normal PowerShell objects.

If the file called C:\log.txt looked like this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\myvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\output\myvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.15.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(progressive), 864x480, q=2-31, 12800 tbn (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:

encoded 2058 frames, 1376.59 fps, 373.36 kbps, 3.66 MB

Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\myvideo2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\output\myvideo2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.15.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(progressive), 864x480, q=2-31, 12800 tbn (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:

encoded 0 frames, 1376.59 fps, 373.36 kbps, 3.66 MB
```

We could run this:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\log.txt" -Raw

[regex]::Matches($content,"(?sm)Input #(?<number>\d+).*?from '(?<filename>.*?)'.*?encoded (?<frames>\d+)") | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Index = $_.Groups["number"].Value 
        Filename = $_.Groups["filename"].Value 
        EncodedFrames = [int]$_.Groups["frames"].Value 
    }

}
```

On its own would return

```
Index Filename        EncodedFrames
----- --------        -------------
0     C:\myvideo.mp4  2058         
1     C:\myvideo2.mp4 0
```

So lets filter that output. Add onto the last line the following i.e. after the Foreach block ending parentheses: `| Where-Object{$_.EncodedFrames -lt 30}` and you would get just the ones you want. Then you could add `| Select-Object -expand Filename` to just get those file names.

All together now

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\log.txt" -Raw

[regex]::Matches($content,"(?sm)Input #(?<number>\d+).*?from '(?<filename>.*?)'.*?encoded (?<frames>\d+)") | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Index = $_.Groups["number"].Value 
        Filename = $_.Groups["filename"].Value 
        EncodedFrames = [int]$_.Groups["frames"].Value 
    }

} | Where-Object{$_.EncodedFrames -lt 30} | Select-Object -expand Filename
```

Comment: This works great! But I got one extra question if you don't mind. Is it possible to seperate the path and the filename? I did something like `(?sm)Input #(?<number>\d+).*?from '(?<filepath>.*\\)(?<filename>.*)'`, but it would match all lines until the end, not like yours which ended at the end of each line.

Comment: No need to fudge the regex to get that. Just use `Split-Path $_.Groups["filename"].Value` on what we already gathered.

Comment: Oh well, didn't thought if that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to output the filenames of all jobs where less then 30 frames where encoded? Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\log.txt"
$index = 0
$indexes = ($content | Select-String -Pattern 'encoded' | foreach {
    if($_ -match "(.*) ([0-9]*) (.*),(.*)") {
        # "remember" the indexes of the matches
        if ([int]$Matches[2] -lt 30) {
            $index
        }
        $index++
    }
})
$index = 0
$content | Select-String -Pattern 'Input' | foreach {
    if($_ -match "(.*) '(.*)':") {
        # output if index matches
        if ($indexes -contains $index) {
            $Matches[2]
        }
        $index++
    }
}
```

Alternative (shorter) solution:

```
get-content "C:\log.txt" | foreach {
    if ($_ -like "Input*" -and $_ -match "(.*) '(.*)':") {
        $file = $Matches[2]
    }
    if ($_ -like "encoded*" -and $_ -match "(.*) ([0-9]*) (.*),(.*)" -and [int]$Matches[2] -lt 30) {
        $file
    }
}
```

Please try if this works with your actual input files.

Also, I think your regex patterns could be improved, but for now it seems they do the job.